# ionic start - ERROR

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to write my first Ionic App but unfortunately I immediately encountered the first problem.
When I launch

```
ionic start HelloW
```

After the directory creation, Terminal ask me if I would like to integrate my new app with Cordova (ecc), then I answer YES and I get the

```
[ERROR] Error with `.\HelloW\node_modules\ionic-angular\package.json file:FILE_NOT FOUND`
```

and

```
[ERROR] Error with `.\HelloW\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\package.json file:FILE_NOT FOUND`
```

How can I resolve this trouble?
Thank you so much!

Comment: use `npm` to install the missing node modules; `ionic-angular` and `@ionic/app-scripts`

Comment: I can't install the  `@ionic/app-scripts` because I get the `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE errno 1 (..)` Falied at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.